# WooComerce SMTP via PHPMailer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress site setup via functions.php to use SMTP with PHPMailer (Snippet below).

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'setup_phpmailer_init' );
function setup_phpmailer_init( PHPMailer $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->Host = 'HOSTNAME'; // for example, smtp.mailtrap.io
    $phpmailer->Port = 587; // set the appropriate port: 465, 2525, etc.
    $phpmailer->Username = 'YOURUSERNAME'; // your SMTP username
    $phpmailer->Password = 'YOURPASSWORD'; // your SMTP password
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // preferable but optional
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();
```

This is working without issue for everything but WooCommerce.  WooCommerce is unable to send email with the below error:

```
2020-08-18T00:36:33+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to setup_phpmailer_init() must be an instance of PHPMailer, instance of PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer given, called in PathToWordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287 and defined in PathToWordpress/web/app/themes/theme-name/functions.php:362
Stack trace:
#0 PathToWordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): setup_phpmailer_init()
#1 PathToWordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 PathToWordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php(544): WP_Hook->do_action()
#3 PathToWordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/pluggable.php(494): do_action_ref_array()
#4 PathToWordpress/web/app/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php(650): wp_mail()
#5 PathToWordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): WC_Emails->no_stock()
#6 PathToWordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply in PathToWordpress/web/app/themes/theme-name/functions.php on line 362
```

What might be causing this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning this line:

---

function setup_phpmailer_init( PHPMailer $phpmailer) {

---

into this (removing PHPMailer) fixed the error

---

function setup_phpmailer_init($phpmailer) {

---

I am not entirely sure why